# Is using .htaccess to map a url to a handler considerd bad practice?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was wondering why every framework is using there own http routing and not using for example apaches `mod_rewrite`.

In frameworks like larave, symfony etc. there redirect every request to `index.php` and routing happens using php.

```php
$app->get('/foo/:id', 'FooController@fooMethod');
```

Why is that? You could use apaches mod_rewrite to do the same thing and probably would be faster than using a php router.

`RewriteRule ^/foo/(\d+)$ index.php?action=FooController@fooMethod&id=$1`

What are the pros and cons using a own php router? 
Is using standard mod_rewrite for routing considerd bad practice?

Comment: A lot of times there is a huge amount of work done before routing actually takes place, config (database, middleware etc.).  There is also the benefit of sticking to all this in one part - PHP code.

Comment: With systems like Magento, the URLs are generally defined through an Admin console; e.g. */noms/peppers/hot* might actually resolve to */?cat=123* but that mapping is stored in the database... so you need to crank up the system to go to the database to find out what you *really* need. Attempting to write Apache rewrite rules, on the fly, from an Admin console seems like a **terrible** idea to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better practice beacuse it's much cleaner to see what's going on, also you have no limits in creativity how it should work, you can customize whatever you want.

Comment: I agree its cleaner but using mod_rewrite you could also easily enable gzip compresson, keep-alive which in a framework you would need some sort of middleware. Also you can define different error pages for different status codes, subdomain routing etc. which you probably can also do with frameworks but its trickier